# c++: convert vector<char> to double

Tags: c++, vector, buffer

I am using `vector<char>` to send and receive data via socket. In this vector I stored data of different types. Unsigned Integer and Doubles.
To decode the data from vector I am using `copy` function.

```
vector<char> myVector = ... smth;
double value = 0.0;
copy(myVector.begin(), myVector.begin() + sizeof(value), &value);
```

It works with Integer without problem. But...

My problem is, that the compile gives out an error `"free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000006d0e30"`. I checked, the problem is with the double value, not with the vector. I looked the address of double value it was (`0x6d0e38`).  Why the program tries to access the pointer backwards? 
I would be glad, if you can say me, what I am doing wrong. And is it the good way to decode message?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Post all the failing code. Note that `sizeof(double) > sizeof(int)`. Cannot rely on the endianness of data being the same on receiver and sender end so no, this is not a good design.

Comment: Please check the size of your vector regardless of "but i know this is more than sizeof(value) !"

Comment: it was just an error. After this message I have just a long list of Qt libraries (Backtrace). 
And yes, I know that double is bigger than int. When I encoded the vector<char> I took the whole size of double.

Comment: @BatchyX: I checked the size of vector too. After the double value there were stored eight unsigned integer. So the size of vector is 40. (8*4 + 8).

Comment: To reiterate @BatchyX's comment, you should verify `myVector.size() <= sizeof(value)` just before you compute `myVector.begin() + sizeof(value)`.

Comment: @Nemo: why the size of vector should be equal or smaller than the size of double value?

Comment: @Steve Townsend: could you suggest the other methods to convert the data?

Comment: For most bullet-proof code, use a serialization library such as Boost.Serialization or Google Protocol Buffers. If you want to roll your own, encapsulate platform-dependent code well to avoid maintenance headaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It works with Integer without problem. But...

It most certainly will **not** work for integers. At least not for integers where `sizeof(int) > 1`! Because it will not write to just one integer, but spread the bytes in `myVector` over `sizeof(T)` integers, thus overwriting random memory. (see nightcracker's answer)

Please just use `memcpy` for this kind of copying:

```
vector<char> myVector = ... smth;
double value = 0.0;
assert(myVector.size() == sizeof(double));
memcpy(&value, &myVector[0], std::min(myVector.size(), sizeof(double)));
// as an alternative to the assert + std::min() above, you could also throw
// an exception if myVector.size() == sizeof(double) does not hold.
// (that's what I'd do if the size should always match exactly)
```

`memcpy` is made exactly for that kind of thing (copying raw memory), and I see no reason to use anything else here. Using `std::copy` does not make it better C++, especially when you're not doing it correctly. `std::copy` is for copying objects, not raw memory.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know. I thought C++ copy() is just reimplementation of C memcpy(). :)
copy(): "Copies the elements..." (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/)
I should read more carefully next time.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you need to cast the pointer accordingly to make `ptr++` use the right size (`sizeof(char)`, opposed to `sizeof(double)`):

```
vector<char> myVector = ... smth;
double value = 0.0;
std::copy(myVector.begin(), myVector.begin() + sizeof(value),
    reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value));
```

Comment: hmmm, i tried your example. The compile did not get an error message. But now the float value are wrong. It's just 0. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this. Send the string representation of the value through the socket.

```
std::stringstream ss;
double value = 0.0;
ss << value;
```

Then use `ss.str()` or if you really need a vector of char:

```
std::vector<char> v(ss.begin(), ss.end());
```

-- edit --
If you really need to keep data binary, do

```
  std::vector<char> v(sizeof(double));
  double val = 0.5;
  std::memcpy(&v[0],(char*)&val,sizeof(val));
  ...
  double* out = (double*)&v[0];
  std::cout << *out << std::endl;
```

Comment: does the stringstream represente the data in binary or character form? I need a binary stream.

Comment: Why would you do that? Introduces converting the data between types and is ~double the data in bytes. Plus stringstream overhead. OP wants binary.

Comment: Why do you need a binary representation ? There many reasons for which you don't want this. What happens if the receiver has a different way to represent the value (big/little endian, 16/32/64bits ...)

Comment: @Ugo: I need the binary data because of the specification for my project!!! (which is not from me) According the specification, all sides of communication will use LITTLE-ENDIAN. So I can not use stringstream :-(

Comment: @Udo: I tried it. The value of double is wrong. The value after the copy is 0.000... And in the buffer there is some data. So it could not be 0.